# Scala: 'val' without initializing

Tags: java, scala

In Java I can easily do something like this:

```
final String str;
if (p() == true) {
    str = "foo";
} else {
    str = "bar";
}
```

How can I archive something like this in Scala? The 'obvious' is, of course, not possible:

```
val str: String
if (p) {
    str = "foo"
} else {
    str = "bar"
}
```

Is there anything equivalent to the thing I can do in Java?

Comment: `var str: String = ""`, `val` is an immutable reference, `var` is not.

Comment: What's wrong with `val str = if(p) "foo" else "bar"` ?

Comment: You could also do `var str: String = _`, but augh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given that in scala if-else blocks are expressions, you can use them like that:

```
val str = 
   if (p) "foo"
   else "bar"
```

This also has an advantage of automatic type deducing compared to Java's syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not have yet the mind-set that in Scala everything is a function/expression :-(

Comment: @Hannes Note that you can also wrap your expression in curly brackets and do even more initialization if you need/want.

Comment: @Hannes not everything, e.g. imports